# Specific File Allowed crossdomain.xml

Tags: flash, actionscript, crossdomain.xml

How can I restrict access to only xml.php (or if not that then the path: /api/*)

To any domain?

I've only found how to do domains but not paths or files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing the link below:

> Step 6: Granular Control of Subdirectories:
>   A cross domain policy file will
>   control access to the directory it
>   resides in, and all the subdirectories
>   beneath it. This is how placing a
>   "allow all" policy file at your domain
>   root allows access to your entire
>   domain. But there may be situations
>   where you want to only allow access to
>   a certain subdirectory. With the
>   latest versions of the Flash Player
>   this requires two XML files. First you
>   need to place a crossdomain.xml file
>   in the root of your domain that allows
>   Flash to process additional cross
>   domain policy files within the
>   subdirectories.

So as understand it, you could allow access to the /api/ path only, using two policy files, one in the root and one in the api directory.

http://blancer.com/tutorials/30030/quick-tip-a-guide-to-cross-domain-policy-files/

Comment: Thanks this seems exactly what I need however what does the all mean in <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/> the link to the policy doc is broken :(

Comment: Page 7 of http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html says it

Comment: Hm.. I set it up the way it said, but it is only requesting crossdomain.xml and stopping. (in logs) Is there anyway to debug a crossdomain request?

Comment: crossdomain policy files only control access to directories. if you want to limit access to only your `xml.php` file, then you will need to place that file in it's own directory add a policy file in that dir, and also update your master cross-domain policy to allow child policys). It's kinda complicated, but the resources @Johnny pointed to should give you the info you need.